# How do I get average and sum in my cross query?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2007

I have asked before, but still no answer.

Is it possible with cross query to do this? (in Access 2007)

I have this table:

```
50 | A1

60 | A1

70 | B1

80 | B1

90 | C1
```

I need to get this result:

```
A1             B1             C1

sum | avg      sum | avg      sum | avg 

55  | 110      75  | 130      90  | 90
```

I try to write this:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Worki.Value) AS XXsum
SELECT Worki.Name AS Name, Worki.Tdate AS Tdate, Worki.ID AS ID
FROM Worki
GROUP BY Worki.Name, Worki.Tdate, Worki.IDPIVOT Worki.Trit
```

How can I get the average and the sum?

Answer (score 1):

There are SQL functions SUM() and AVG() you can use.  To get the sum of each of the types A1, B1, C1, you could use the following query:

```
SELECT Worki.ID, SUM(Worki.Value), AVG(Worki.Value) FROM Worki GROUP BY Worki.ID, Worki.Name, Worki.Tdate
```

Which returns

```
A1    110    55
B1    150    75
C1    90     90
```

Sorry I'm no help with the formatting

Comment: but he wants A1, B1, etc to be the column headers.

Comment: Shouldn't a TRANSFORM (i.e., crosstab) on that result be doable? Sure, it's a little tricky to get the average and sum into the same column, but that can be done with an expression (either in the crosstab or in the source query that is being TRANSFORMed).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this with a crosstab query - you can only have one Value column in a crosstab.  I think you'll have to build two queries - one for sum, one for average, then combine the information somehow.  They will, at least, have the same columns.